# How to completely delete ruby on rails project from computer, heroku, and github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

How do I completely delete a ruby on rails project from my computer, heroku, and github. I know the obvious, delete the project file, delete the github repo, and delete the heroku app, but are there any smaller steps i need to do. I just wanna make sure that if i happen to make a new project with the same name as a project i deleted, there wouldnt be a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to delete the database (the local version of it, on your computer). That's the only other thing.

Comment: Did you create a database? If you don't remember specifically creating one, it's likely you used sqlite, in which case your database would have been stored inside your project folder and is probably already gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you used RVM or the like, it's also a good idea to delete the gemset or any gems installed specifically for your project. See http://rvm.io/gemsets/deleting. When I first started with RVM I created gem sets for everything - and always forgot to delete them when I deleted the project.